# Trouble with this C++ snippet

Tags: c++

I don't understand what this snippet is do, if anyone could explain it would help out a great deal.

```
    bool result;
    for (std::set<_Tp>::const_iterator o = objs.begin(); o != objs.end(); o++)
    {
      //confusion here, what does this do
      result |= accept(c, *o, bid); //accept returns a bool
    }

    return result;
  }
```

I know that the `|=` compound operator does a bitwise OR but what does that mean for the value of result? If accept returns true then the value of result will stay true, right?

I guess I don't really understand why the `|=` is there instead of `=`

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: It really should probably be a `||=` in this context.  There are other ways to write this that are more STL-ish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|=` is a bitwise or, not a logical or. You have removed the logic out of the snippet, but basically what it does is return true as long as any object within the set is 'accepted', whatever the definition of `accept` is.

Comment: ahh I see, I tried to abstract the other code because I didn't want to clutter the example, but c is a list of controller type objects. So as long as one controller takes ownership of the object it returns true. thanks!

Comment: Note that the initial value of the automatic variable `result` will be undefined, so it could be set to true to begin with. You probably want to explicitly set it to false.

Answer (score 2):

`x |= y` is equivalent to `x = x | y`.  So what

```
result |= accept(...);
```

does is set `result` to `true` if `accept` returns `true` -- and leave it alone if `accept` returns `false`.

`|`, as opposed to `||`, is a *bitwise* operation, but for bool values it gives the same result.  (And there is no `||=` operator, probably because `||` has short-circuit semantics.)

I hope that wasn't all the code.  In the code you showed us, `result` is uninitialized.

Comment: I wasn't sure myself but apparently there is no `||=` (see [Operators in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)).

Answer (score 0):

It checks if any one of return values from the function `accept` is true. If you replaced the `|=` with the `=` then if the last call to accept returned false then the final result would also be false.  Any previous value would be overwritten. Using `|=` instead allows you to keep the previous results.